# How to convert a standard json file to aws sqs cli json input file format for powershell

Tags: json, powershell, amazon-sqs

I want to send a standard formatted json file via a powershell CLI commend line to a aws sqs normal queue.

The following command works fine

```
PS> aws sqs send-message --queue-url https://sqs.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/xxxx/Test --message-body "Data delivery" --message-attribute file://send-message10.json
```

The file send-message10.json has the following format:

```
{
  "City": {
    "DataType": "String",
    "StringValue": "Any City"
  },
  "Population": {
    "DataType": "Number",
    "StringValue": "1250800"
  }
}
```

Now I want to transfer a standard formatted json data.json to the same queue
The file data.json has the following format:

```
[
  {
    "DateandTime": "2021-01-14T16:30:31.000Z",
    "Value1": 3,
    "Value2": 13939.71
  }
]
```

How can I easily either
a) modify the command line so that my data.json file is accepted or
b) convert the data.json file into the send-message10.json format to be accepted by the command line?

Comment: I could resolve the topic via a jq script. https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Answer (score 0):

Your data.json is an array with a single name-value pair.. so, convert it to a PSCustomObject, reference the first element in the array, and convert it back to JSON.

```
(@'
[
  {
    "DateandTime": "2021-01-14T16:30:31.000Z",
    "Value1": 3,
    "Value2": 13939.71
  }
]
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json)[0] | ConvertTo-Json
```

results in:

```
{
    "DateandTime":  "2021-01-14T16:30:31.000Z",
    "Value1":  3,
    "Value2":  13939.71
}
```

You can probably add more logic on the command line, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dan.